# Meteor: How to know which template helper is throwing an exception

Tags: meteor

After having changed the semantics of a Session variable used in lots of places in the code, I am left with a regression where I get the "Exception in template helper" error at page load.

So I screwed up, and there is somewhere where I am using that variable where I have not modified the code to handle the new semantics. But I can't find where....

The traceback gives me no clue, as it has only entries from the meteor javascript files, no informtion about my application files:

```
 Exception in template helper: Error: $in needs an array
    at Error (native)
    at Object.ELEMENT_OPERATORS.$in.compileElementSelector (http://jesper-lab:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1887:15)
    at http://jesper-lab:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1569:19
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://jesper-lab:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
    at operatorBranchedMatcher (http://jesper-lab:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1549:5)
    at compileValueSelector (http://jesper-lab:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1453:12)
    at http://jesper-lab:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1432:9
    at Function._.each._.forEach (http://jesper-lab:3000/packages/underscore.js?0a80a8623e1b40b5df5a05582f288ddd586eaa18:164:22)
    at compileDocumentSelector (http://jesper-lab:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1415:5)
    at _.extend._compileSelector (http://jesper-lab:3000/packages/minimongo.js?e8806aa7782b729b2517ebc0cd10b321667f1427:1392:12)
```

Is there any way I can find out WHICH template helper is throwing this exception? (Besides putting breakpoints in all of them (hundreds...))

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I am afraid I never did. Ended up dividing things into smaller chunks until I isolated the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it's the best possible way but what I do is use a generic try_catch function:

```
@try_catch = (f) ->
    return (args) ->
        try
            f(args)
        catch e
            console.log e
```

and wrap it around every template helper I want to debug.